# Has someone used pt-online-schema-change for altering a table with 1x millions entries?

Tags: mysql, database, alter-table, percona

I would like to get feedback experience on adding a column into a table with 1x million entries..

How long did it take ? was it truly without locking..

We are using mysql with innoDB..

Comment: I've done it on a table containing 21 million. Took about 30 minutes. Time's going to depend heavily on your disks, amount of data in each row, indexes, etc., but I've found it quite reliable and it's non-locking by design.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a poll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with 1milion entries, but with 420k. Took something around 10 min. I believe it was without locking.